# htaccess redirect to wamp local address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an already online hosted website which I have downloaded and configured for wamp. The only problem which occurred is that if I click on any link on my local website I will get redirected to my online website.

Unfornutally I cannot set up my htaccess so that it's changing the online links to the local server.

So for instance:

Having a link on a site which redirects to `www.example.com/blog` should be rewritten to redirect to `example.dev/blog`.

For that I have tried something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.dev/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it does not work.

**EDIT**:
A more in depth example:

I have a website which address is: `www.example.com` its local wamp address is `example.dev`. Now I have a link `<a href="http://www.example.com/shop.html">Shop</a>` within a *index.html* of the local `example.dev` root. And now I need a way to redirect `http://www.example.com/shop.html` to `http://example.dev/shop.html`. This should be apply to all sub pages not only for shop. Also for style sheets etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things must be changed in the rules

- `HTTP_HOST` contains only the host, nothing else. So the condition should rather be

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
  ```
- The target will be interpreted as a file system path. To redirect it to another host, you must specify a complete URL including the protocol (`http`)

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.dev/$1 [R,L]
  ```

---

Another approach to redirect one site to another wholesale, can be done by [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

```
Redirect /blog http://example.dev/blog
```

or doing this with all requests

```
Redirect / http://example.dev/
```

---

Looking at your update, it seems you don't need .htaccess at all. You must rather change the relevant links to either

```
<a href="http://www.example.dev/shop.html">Shop</a>
```

or better yet, don't use absolute URLs

```
<a href="/shop.html">Shop</a>
```

Similar for style sheets or Javascript files.

Comment: using your first approach which makes totally sense for me now, does not work. If I access the local website via `example.dev/.....` I am still getting redirected to `www.example.de/.....`  if I click on a link on the website.

Comment: Rewrite rules only handle requests, they cannot change the HTML delivered. This must be done in the PHP code. Although, this sounds like you're using absolute URLs.